# Mouseover event for Fabric JS object added with React useEffect doesn't trigger

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, fabricjs, use-effect

I'm trying to capture mouseover events for fabric object added some time after the canvas was initialized. I'm using react, so I'm doing that in a `useEffect` hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    canvasRef.current = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
      width: 300,
      height: 600,
      backgroundColor: "#666",
      selection: false
    });

    canvasRef.current.add(
      new fabric.Rect({
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        top: 100,
        left: 100,
        fill: "#660000"
      })
    );
    canvasRef.current.on("mouse:over", function (e) {
      console.log("mouse over", e.e.clientX, e.e.clientY, e.target);
    });


    canvasRef.current.requestRenderAll();

    setTimeout(() => {
      canvasRef.current.add(
        new fabric.Rect({
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          top: 200,
          left: 100,
          fill: "#666600"
        })
      );
      canvasRef.current.requestRenderAll();
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

For some reason, only the object added immediately after the canvas was initialized responds to the `mouse:over` event.

The other 2 rectangles added later (one with timeout, the other in a `useEffect` hook based on change of state) do not log the target when hovering.

I'm not sure if this is because fabric JS interacts in a strange way with react or something else, but I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction here.

See this codesandbox for the full code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiberjs-mouseevent-test-k95zuq?file=/src/App.js

See this example that doesn't use React but uses timeouts, and somehow the hover function works properly:

https://codepen.io/zinkkrysty/pen/ExEMjLo?editors=0011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

> With Strict Mode starting in React 18, whenever a component mounts in
> development, React will simulate immediately unmounting and remounting
> the component:

So `useEffect` is called twice. You should properly deinitialize the component. For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  return () => canvasRef.current.dispose();
}, [])
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. So you're saying that my code should actually work, but only in production?

Comment: @Cristian Yes, exactly.